# How to read and write files in python for Arabic

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python. I am using Python 2.7.3. I tried to read from Arabic text to do some processes on it for my program idea.

but it prints unreadable output

this is a script of my code:

```
>>> fname = open (r"C:\Python27\نجود.txt ", "rb")
>>> text = fname.read()
>>> print text
ï»؟ط§ظ„ط³ظ„ط§ظ… ط¹ظ„ظٹظƒظ… ط£ظ†ط§ ط¨طµط¯ط¯ طھط¬ط±ط¨ط© ظ‡ط°ط§ 
ط§ظ„ط¨ط±ظ†ط§ظ…ط¬ ظپظٹ ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ†. ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ† ط±ط§ط¦ط¹ ظˆط¬ظ…ظٹظ„, ``ظˆظ„ظƒظ† طھط¬ط±ط¨ط© ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ† ظ…ط¹ ط§ظ„ط¹ط±ط¨ظٹ ط³طھظƒظˆظ† ظ…ط®طھظ„ظپط©!. ط¨ط§ظٹط«ظˆظ† ط±ط§ط¦ط¹ ظˆظٹط³طھط­ظ‚ ط§ظ„طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©.
```

I tried many solutions like:

```
text= fname.encoding() #or encode , but it did not work and gave me this error:
########
text= fname.encoding()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

try to put `# encoding: utf-8` in the top of code file but it did not give any change.

also try to do this:

```
fname = open (r"C:\Python27\نجود.txt ", "r", encoding='utf-8')
```

but it gave me this error:

```
fname = open (r"C:\Python27\نجود.txt ", "r", encoding='utf-8')
 TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

any suggesions? thanks in advance.

Comment: Brilliant video on encoding in Python by Ned Batchelder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc

Comment: I recommend you to read official Python docs about Unicode: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html Thus, you'll clearly understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from a file will return a `str` which, in Python2, is an arbitrary byte string (which might be a UTF-8 encoded string of unicode characters, but it could also be binary data like the contents of a JPG file or similar).

If you know that it is a UTF-8 encoded string of characters, you should *decode* it:

```
decoded = text.decode('utf8')
```

This will produce a `unicode` object which is a string of unicode characters.  If you handle this, Python will try to do everything properly.  E. g. depending on your terminal, printing this should work as expected:

```
print decoded
```

Comment: In Python3, btw, things are different.  When opening a file one can/should give the file's encoding, and reading from it will already return a string of Unicode characters (called `str` in Python3).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  "Thank you" comments are not necessary.  Instead, if an answer is helpful, you should upvote it (the upwards triangle above the number left of the answer).  If an answer solves your issue completely (and is the best answer of several), you should accept it by pressing the check mark left to it.  This way others quickly find the solutions.

Comment: can  i use decoded as string variable and work with the text normally? because it returns an unreadable output also when i use split function

Comment: Yes, `decoded` is a unicode string.  I guess you may have some LTR⋄RTL problem because Arabic is RTL (right-to-left).  The direction switch between the parts of a text is encoded using a special unprintable character.  This may well be at the beginning of the string and the counterpart at the end.  If this is correct and now you split this, only the first segment will have the RTL-switch in front and only the last segment will have the LTR-switch trailing.  Maybe that is causing your trouble.

Comment: i think u r right! because when i open the file, although the text was wrote in Arabic,  but it appears on the left side of the Notepad program. So what is the solution ?

Comment: Good question.  Never handled RTL texts before, so that's a problem for someone else.  But I propose to open a new question stating clearly that you have RTL problems, then probably the right people are more intrigued.  A basic idea without background knowledge:  It's a little as with escape sequences for colors in terminals.  They switch the color, you switch the direction. If one cuts those in the middle, the state at the cut needs preservation and restoration at the beginning of the second part.  But just so much for theory.  No practical solution I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open the file in the right encoding. Arabic on Windows is usually `windows-1256` or sometimes it can be `utf-8`.

For 2.7.3, make sure you are opening the file correctly:

```
import io

with io.open(r"C:\Python27\نجود.txt ", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
       print(line)
```